# How to redirect to cart page using wp_redirect

Tags: wp-redirect

I am trying to the redirect on a cart page using a bellow code but,I am not able to redirect on cart page .

```
wp_redirect("'.home_url('cart').'");
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please use get_page_by_path

```
wp_redirect( get_page_by_path( 'cart' ) );
exit();
```

[Reference link for get page by path](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_page_by_path)

Comment: You might want to test that weird quoting: `echo "'.get_page_by_path('cart').'";` The function never runs.

Comment: Man, please! Start using the WYSIWYG editor! Click the [edit] link and fix it. I already commented on your other answers with the exact same notes. Aside from that @CharlesClarkson is right and aside from that, you're missing the `die/exit` at the end or around the function.

Comment: I removed the downvote and fixed your code. `"'.foo().'"` will break. For the future: Please test your code before posting something that breaks. Else you'll quickly get a lot of downvotes and loose reputation points and the capabilities.

Comment: `get_page_by_path()` returns a `WP_post` object of the page and not a URL to the page. To get the URL to a page by name, use `get_permalink(get_page_by_path($pagename))`

Answer (score 1):

Try it like the following. The `exit()` is necessary to stop other code from running and redirect right there.

```
exit( wp_redirect( home_url( "cart" ) ) );
```